# Can't boot into ubuntu with LUKS. System hangs at "cryptsetup: sda5_crypt set up successfully""

Tags: mount, luks

I've looked at a couple methods but this is all new territory for me. 
Workflow:
I boot up my machine, then I'm asked for my pass phrase, I successfully enter it and I get the "cryptsetup: sda5_crypt set up successfully".
After that the system hangs. I don't any functionality, no ctrl+alt+F[1-0] or ctrl+alt+backspace. I read somewhere that it might be a problem with xorg and not with LUKS. I also tried booting into a live cd and mounting the partition but I don't know how to access the encrypted contents or where anything is mounted.
Any help is appreciated.

**UPDATE**:
I was able to mount the ecryptfs with an ubuntu-mate live cd and using `ecryptfs-recover-private`. But it mounts the fs as read only. How do I get it to mount r/w?

**UPDATE 2:**
I was able to remount with r/w permissions using this command `sudo mount -i -o remount,rw /path/to/your/Device/or/.Private` 
I still can't boot into the machine though.

Comment: Maybe it is mounted R/O because it is damaged. Try to run an fsck on it?

Comment: This might as well be nonsense, but I had the same problem for a while now and I noticed that it has to do with my laptops internal power management when it's on battery. Because it somehow worked when the power cable was plugged in.
So I switched off the power management in the BIOS settings that would set the machine to power saving mode when on battery, as my OS (Pop) has it's own power management (on a different level, for sure, but I don't have any problems so far).
And voilá: The thing boots and decrypts on battery, too.